# Animation disappearing when closing and opening a project

Tags: animation, keyframes

I keep having issues with vanishing animation in Blender and I can't figure out if it's something I'm doing.

I have created an animation made up entirely of text to vocals. Each word is keyframed to appear and dissappear in the same place using the 'globally disable in viewports'icon in the scene collection. It plays fine. I close the project and reopen it. It's still there playing okay.

Then, I open a few different blender projects or work on something fresh. When I reopen my animation file and play it, none of the text will appear on screen, despite all the keyframes still being there. Nothing I try makes any difference.

Bizarrely, I have to select all the objects in the scene collection, delete them and then command Z to undo the delete. Then they all reappear as they should on the timeline. If I only delete and undo one, just that object appears.

Is there some sort of cache that I don't know about that is causing this problem?